# WIX: change/repair/remove buttons disabled in WixUI_MaintenanceTypeDlg

Tags: wix

I'm using WIX to create an installer and WixUI_Mondo for the UI. Everything had gone well until I stumbled upon a problem with MaintenanceTypeDlg. Things work finely when I install the application, however when I click the MSI later on (when the app is installed), I get change/repair/remove buttons grayed out.

Here are relevant parts of my installation project (sorry, didn't manage to put them inline, since they got cut by the forum software, so had to upload them to pastebin.ca): http://pastebin.ca/1958654.

So, as you see, I'm setting ARPNO*** properties to zero, and, what's more, the log shows these properties set to zero during install. I've also tried to swap *include* directives, so that UI goes after ControlPanel - unfortunately, with no luck. Any ideas about what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the ARPNO* properties; as the documentation says, "setting them" -- i.e., to anything -- disables the ARP behavior.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much - it worked! But, but... this is really weird.